# Connect Evolution to Exchange in Fedora 18

Tags: fedora, gnome3, exchange-2010, evolution, fedora-18

I just installed Fedora 18 x86_64 on my laptop and trying to set up my email and calendar from work. We are on a Microsoft Exchange 2010 server, but I'm able to connect to the email/calendar from my Android phone.

When I tried to add my Exchange account under Online Accounts, it seemed to work and the email and calendar show up as switches set to on, but Evolution does not include the exchange account in its list.

Am I missing something? Is someone else able to connect to an Exchange server through the new Gnome settings?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I found some random blog/forum post that said after a logout and log back in, the accounts would show up. ....And that exactly worked for me...When I did this I had like 13 copies of my Exchange account configured in evolution.....

Evo + exchangeMAPI is working well for me now -- well except GAL. I skirted around this by adding my AD as and LDAP source and it mostly works just fine.

Comment: I need a little clarification, you're saying that just use Evolution + Exchange MAPI directly as opposed to using Online Accounts and then you lost me.